# git merge --squash -X theirs <commit>

Tags: git, merge

I would like to clean a very messy branch into a new branch where I want only to get some states.

The initial solution for this is a copy-paste method:

```
$ git checkout 1234567
$ cp -r . /tmp/git
$ git checkout -b new old
$ git ls-files | xargs rm 
$ cp -r /tmp/git .
$ git commit -a -m "Step 1"
...
```

I thought the `git merge --squash -X theirs` would have the same effect, but even the `Automating merge went well`, when I `git diff --stat 1234567` I still see differences.

I obviously missed something about the `--squash -X theirs`.

How can I reproduce my copy-paste method using a native git command. The idea is to squash a state of a commit into another branch, not only the diff as normally rebase does.

Another way would be to use this command:

```
$ git ls-files | xargs rm && git checkout 1234567 $(git ls-tree --name-only -r 1234567)
$ git commit -a -m "New commit name"
```

Actually I've added this alias to my `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    import = "!sh -c 'git cat-file -e $0 && \
                      git ls-files | xargs rm -f && \
                      git checkout $0 $(git ls-tree --name-only -r $0)'"
```

Comment: So, you want to create commit with tree from `1234567` and with parent `old`? `git commit-tree -p old -m "Step 1" 1234567^{tree}`

Comment: I am not sure I understand your command here.

Comment: `git commit-tree` create commit from specified tree. `1234567^{tree}` means tree used in commit `1234567`, so new commit will have identical content. `-p` allows you to specify parents of new commit: `-p parent1 -p parent2 -p parent3`. `-m` specify commit message, you can also pipe commit message to the *stdin*. Hash of new commit will be printed on *stdout*. So, you does not need to copy anything, you just create new commit with same tree.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. I am going to test it